# preserving column names in sklearn preprocessing with normalizer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
data = {'First Column Name':  ['12.513362', '13.081390', '15.045193'],
        'Second Column Name': ['24.597206', '25.526964', '29.153882'],
        '3rd Column Name':  ['nan', 'nan', 'nan'],
        '4th Column Name':  ['nan', '2.545', '3.89'],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First Column Name','Second Column Name','3rd Column Name', '4th Column Name'])
```

`df` has three rows and 4 columns. Now I apply the following preprocessing with normalization.

```
fill_NaN = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
df = pd.DataFrame(fill_NaN.fit_transform(df))
normalizer = preprocessing.Normalizer().fit(df)
df=normalizer.transform(df)
```

I get an out NumPy array of 3 rows and 3 columns. One column is discarded which contains all `nan` which is fine.

How can I preserve the original column names with this normalization?

Comment: numpy arrays don't have column names.  pandas dataframes do.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleImputer` is the one responsible for dropping the column here. You can detect which column (index) gets dropped with the attribute `statistics_`: it will be `np.nan`.

> **statistics_ : *array of shape (n_features,)***
>
> ...
>
> During transform, features corresponding to `np.nan` statistics will be discarded.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html